# Get locale from firebase and add to angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-translate

I am trying to get locale data from firebase and put it in the module angular-translate. My problem is that the data is not being loaded.

I have a firebase database with the following structure:

```
en/jumbotron/title
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('cribatec', ['ngSanitize','firebase','pascalprecht.translate']);

var database = firebase.database().ref('en/')

var localeEN = {
  jumbotron_title: '{{database.jumbotron.title}}'
};

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  // add translation table
  $translateProvider
    .useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize')
    .translations('en', localeEN)
    .preferredLanguage('en');
}]);
```

index.html

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "*******",
    authDomain: "***.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://***.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "***.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "****"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<h2>{{ 'jumbotron_title' | translate }}</h2>
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [retreiving data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data)

Comment: I already know how to retrieve data and as you can see the database variable is correct. The problem is that its not working.

(I forgot to copy paste the firebase config in index.html, so main post is not updated)

Comment: Yes but nowhere in your code are you retreiving any data from firebase. Something like: database.child('jumbotron').on('value', function(snapshot) {//Do something with snapshot data});